# Safari 9 XMLHttpRequest Blob file download

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, filereader

Hello JavaScript gurus,

I need a file download functionality using XMLHttpRequest (with responseType="blob") that works in Safari 9+.

At the moment I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) like this:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // using FileSaver.js to save blob  
    saveAs(xhr.response, filename);
    // notify download finished, resolve promise
    defer.resolve(true);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

which works fine in all main browsers but not in current version (9.x) of Safari.
I'll get a "Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted". Usually a download is a zip file but I also tried to set "application/octet-stream".

I have one requirement: I need to know when then download has finished on client-side so using an iframe is no option (I guess).

I'm thankful for any hint how to download a file in Safari using XHR (no Flash).

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:
There is no solution!

See also: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/119222

Thanks Safari ... my new almost IE6